# Icons are not on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm new to CSS and HTML and I got stuck at the easy problem...
I use fontawesome and the icons are not inline(fa fa-volume-down and fa fa-music)
Anyway to fix it?Thank you for spending your time for me!

Here is live example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YegorGunko/sygt68ev/)(you can see that the volume icon is higher than the music note icon)

Here is my code :

```
<nav class="player">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle player_play action"></i>
      <div class="radio_volume">
        <i class="fa fa-volume-down volume_icon"></i>
        <span><i class="fa fa-music radio_icon accent_color"></i>&nbsp;Anison</span>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-list-ul radio_select action"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
.player{padding:.75rem 1rem;margin-bottom:1rem}
.player_play{font-size:36px}
.radio_icon{padding-right:5px;}
.radio_select{font-size:20px}
.volume_icon{font-size:20px;margin-right:10px}
```

Comment: The font sizes are not the same between `fa fa-volume-down` and `fa fa-music`. They don't occupy the same vertical height, because you've changed them. I'm sure you're trying to do it because you disagree with the defaults set out in FA, but not all glyphs occupy the same space, so they *will not* ever be perfectly aligned with each other. If you place a simple `1px` border around `i` tags, you will see that they do in fact occupy the same space, but their glyphs are not occupying the same space within. If you are fixated on perfection, you can go your way, resize fonts, and position them.

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks)

Comment: my favorite way to correct those kinds of things is setting for example "position:relative; top:2px;" because they won't then affect the flow around them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Outline

- Demo has 3 examples in 3 sizes.
- Instead of setting the icons' sizes by `font-size`, the [**`.fa-Nx`**](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#larger) class was used. **Note:** I used `.fa-1x` which isn't a real `.fa` class, I placed it there out of a strange need for symmetry  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- 90% of the original layout, classes, and styles were removed.
- 2 layers wrap the `<i>`

  - `nav.player` `display:table`
  - `div.layer` `display:table-row`
- All `i.fa` and `b` `display:table-cell`
- Besides `display`, these added properties are important as well:

  - `vertical-align:baseline`
  - `line-height:1`
- Added a function that toggles an outline over the player components to help visually compare alignment and spacing. Click any of the players' menu icon to the right.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/Lz897orc/)**

### Demo

```js
/* This just toggles a outline of each player
|| to show how each component is aligned.
|| click any menu icon to the right of player
*/
$('.fa-list-ul').on('click', function(e) {
  $('i,b').toggleClass('grid');
})
```

```css
.player {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.layer {
  display: table-row
}

i.fa {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer
}

.fa-play-circle {
  width: 15%
}

.fa-volume-down {
  width: 15%
}

.fa-music {
  width: 10%;
}

.fa-list-ul {
  text-align: right;
  width: 15%;
}

b {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

#p3 b {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#p2 b {
  font-size: 2em;
}

#p1 b {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.grid {
  outline: 3px solid cyan
}
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<main id='main'>
  <nav id='p3' class="player">
    <div class='layer'>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-volume-down fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-music fa-3x"></i>
      <b>Anison</b>
      <i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <hr>
  <nav id='p2' class="player">
    <div class='layer'>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-volume-down fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-music fa-2x"></i>
      <b>Anison</b>
      <i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <hr>
  <nav id='p1' class="player">
    <div class='layer'>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-1x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-volume-down fa-1x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-music fa-1x"></i>
      <b>Anison</b>
      <i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-1x"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</main>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@2.2.4,bootstrap@3.3.7"></script>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can align it correctly using `vertical-align`.

```
.volume_icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

result
[image]

Comment: Yes, they really are. I used a pixel ruler to check?

Comment: @YegorGunko See image ^

Comment: Thanks everyone :3

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and let me know if there is any error

```
<nav class="player">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <i class="fa fa-play-circle player_play action"></i>
   <div class="radio_volume">
     <ul>
       <li><i class="fa fa-volume-down volume_icon"></i></li>
       <li><span><i class="fa fa-music radio_icon accent_color">
         </i>&nbsp;Anison</span></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     <i class="fa fa-list-ul radio_select action"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Check the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/sygt68ev/1/

Comment: Oh thanks, it's working, but not the play button aren't inline... Is there any way to center all the icons in the nav on the same line?

Comment: So you want all the icons on a same line isn't it?

Comment: It just seems a little unorthordox given the layout I presume you're wanting. E.g. nesting the icons isn't needed

Comment: See what you are trying to do is building a navbar i suggest you to take a look at the tags first because as others pointed out your code is unorthodox  however take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black